# A question about $O(3,1)$

Tags: lie-algebras, orthogonal-groups

Recall that $O(3,1)$ is the collection of matrices $A\in M_4(\mathbb R)$ such that
$$A\begin{pmatrix}1 &&&\\&1&&\\&&1&\\&&&-1\end{pmatrix}A^T=\begin{pmatrix}1 &&&\\&1&&\\&&1&\\&&&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Let $\psi\in \mathfrak o(3,1)$ be an element in its Lie algebra. Can we find a $Q\in O(3,1)$ such that 
$$Q\psi Q^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&a&&\\-a&0&&\\&&0&b\\&&b&0\end{pmatrix}$$
for some $a,b\in \mathbb R$?

Formally, for any $\psi\in \mathfrak o(3,1)$ can we find an $\hat \psi \in \mathfrak o(2)\oplus \mathfrak o(1,1)$, such that $\psi, \hat \psi$ belong to the same $O(3,1)$-cojugate class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. E.g. $\psi=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1&1\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is nilpotent: $\psi^3=0$. If your $\phi=\begin{pmatrix}0&a&0&0\\-a&0&0&0\\0&0&0&b\\0&0&b&0\end{pmatrix}$ was $Q\psi Q^{-1}$, we would have $\phi^3=\begin{pmatrix}0&-a^3&0&0\\a^3&0&0&0\\0&0&0&b^3\\0&0&b^3&0\end{pmatrix}=0$, whence $a=b=\phi=\psi=0$, contradiction.

---

**Edit** (Re: your amended question below): If all (or even some) eigenvalues of $\psi$ are nonzero then yes, $\psi$ is conjugate to one of your $\phi$'s. It is equivalent but easier to classify adjoint orbits of the covering group $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbf C)$, whose Lie algebra consists of all
$$
Z=J(\mathbf z) := \frac1{2i}\begin{pmatrix}z_3&z_1-iz_2\\z_1+iz_2&-z_3\end{pmatrix},
\qquad \mathbf z = \mathbf a + \mathbf bi\in\mathbf C^3.
$$
The Lie algebra isomorphism maps $Z$ to $\psi=\begin{pmatrix}j(\mathbf a)&\mathbf b\\{}^t\mathbf b&0\end{pmatrix}$ where $j(\mathbf a)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-a_3&a_2\\a_3&0&-a_1\\-a_2&a_1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Now $\det(\lambda\mathbf1-2iZ)=\lambda^2 - (\mathbf z,\mathbf z)=(\lambda+\zeta)(\lambda-\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a square root of $(\mathbf z,\mathbf z):=$ $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2$ $=\|\mathbf a\|^2-\|\mathbf b\|^2+2i(\mathbf a,\mathbf b)$. So there are two cases:

- if $(\mathbf z,\mathbf z)= 0$ then $Z$ is nilpotent, hence either 0 or (Jordan) conjugate to $\smash{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)}$ $= J(i\mathbf e_1-\mathbf e_2)$ which maps to my nilpotent $\psi$ above (eigenvalues: 0).
- if $(\mathbf z,\mathbf z)\ne 0$ then $Z$ is diagonalizable and hence conjugate to $\smash{\frac1{2i}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\zeta&0\\0&-\zeta\end{smallmatrix}\right)}=J(\zeta\mathbf e_3)$ which maps to your $\phi$ if $\zeta = a + bi$ (eigenvalues: $\pm ai,\pm b$).

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. I see this case now, but how about the case of all eigenvalues do not equal to zero?

Comment: Or in a coordinate-free language, the  $ab$-matrix is diagonalizable (semisimple), with eigenvalues $\pm ai, \pm b$, whereas the Lie algebra $\frak{o}(3,1)$ (being semisimple and noncompact) has non-zero nilpotent elements. For a Lie algebra with a higher rank simple component, there are also elements that are neither nilpotent nor semisimple (cf Jordan decomposition).

Comment: @VictorProtsak Yes, please email me, too.

Comment: I feel quite sorry! Your answer helps me a lot and I did accept your answer. But I think the left bottom of my mouse get something wrong (sometimes the one click becomes double click)! Moreover, as Protsak noted, does this phenomenon appear in higher dimensional $\mathfrak{o}(m,n)$? I am not familiar with this topic, would you offer some literatures about it? Thanks again! This comment maybe too late for you.

Comment: @A.T.Saaki No problem! Yes, the situation is similar (though more complicated, as Victor notes) for all semisimple groups. For the big picture I'd recommend §3 of [Vogan's ICM paper](http://mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1986.1/). For more details see [Collingwood-McGovern](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1251060) which despite the title, also has a chapter on semisimple orbits.